# Jquery tabs and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

i am using jquery to create the following using this code

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#documents").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
  });
</script>
```

Here it is in firefox working like in every other browser like this:

[image]

but in **IE 8** ... it does this  but in 7 its fine.

[image]

I think it is somethin to do with the script opacity but i cant get it to work. does any one have any idea.

Cheers

Comment: What does your markup look like? Have you used those "id" values more than once in the page?

Comment: Looks like it was the fact we were using an external JS scource on a secure site... wierd. works now though by using  local JS. Woot woot :) erm how u close a thread lol

Answer (score 7):

I see that you got it working by fixing the jQuery/UI reference, but just as a note, you can have multiple code blocks inside a single `<script>` tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#documents").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
  });
</script>
```

Also, you can run as much as you want inside any `document.ready`, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
    $("#documents").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
  });
</script>
```

And last, you can have use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to reduce the code even further, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { //shortcut for $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content, #documents").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
  });
</script>
```